# Adjusting x-ticks from defined range in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to change xticks to 0, 10.00, 20.00, 30.00, 40.00, 50.00? It would be great if it is not hard code as the future data may not be 5000.
[image]

I tried creating xs array for labeling x-axis but the result axis had all values instead of just 5 like previous auto adjustment.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plot_result is numpy.ndarray of (8,5001)
plt.imshow(plot_result, aspect='auto')

xs = np.arange(0, 50.01, 0.01) # time

plt.imshow(plot_result, aspect='auto')
plt.xticks(range(len(xs)), xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to actually set the data range of the image, such that the first pixel is at `0` and the last pixel at `50`.

This can be done using the `extent` argument of [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow).

> ***`extent`*** : scalars (left, right, bottom, top), optional, default: None
>   The location, in data-coordinates, of the lower-left and upper-right corners. If None, the image is positioned such that the pixel centers fall on zero-based (row, column) indices.

In order to preserve the datapoints being shown as the middle of the pixel, some small calculations are needed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

z = np.random.rand(8,5001)
xmin = 0; xmax=50; dx=(xmax-xmin)/(z.shape[1]-1.)
ymin = 0; ymax=7; dy=(ymax-ymin)/(z.shape[0]-1.)
extent = [xmin-dx/2.,xmax+dx/2., ymin-dy/2.,ymax+dy/2. ]
plt.imshow(z, aspect='auto', extent=extent)

plt.show()
```

[image]